# how to use if-else inside the map return react js

Tags: reactjs

Code:-

```
{comments.map((comment) => {
    //Display Hex to base64 image format
    const base64 = Buffer.from(comment.Thumbnail, 'hex').toString('base64');
    //console.log(base64);

    return (
        <tr key={comment.SlugName} ref={tbodyRef} tabIndex={0} className="border_bottom" onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, comment.idx)}>
            <td style={{ color: "white", width: "200px" }}>
                <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`} alt="Clip Thumbnail" width="100%" />
            </td>
            <td style={{ color: "white", width: "440px" }}>{comment.ClipName}</td>
            <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.SlugName}</td>
            <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.ChannelName}</td>
            <td style={{ color: "white", width: "140px" }}>
                {
                    if (comment.Status === 1) {
                        <button type="submit">Play</button>
                    } else if(comment.Status === 2){
                        console.log(comment.Status);
                    } else if(comment.Status === 3){
                        console.log(comment.Status);
                    } else{
                        console.log(comment.Status);
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td style={{ color: "white" }}> 
                {comment.Mode === true ? <RiArrowLeftRightFill style={{ color: "white" }} /> : <RiArrowLeftRightFill style={{ color: "#363c44" }} />}
            </td>
            <td style={{ color: "white" }}>{comment.StartTime}</td>
            <td style={{ color: "white" }}>{comment.Duration}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

I want when comment. Status is 1 it displays a button in a webpage as a comment. Status is 2 also displays a button with name cue as goes on with comment. Status 3,4
how can I display the btn with comment status 1,2,3

API:-

```
[
    {
        "ClipName": "Evernote Hacked, Time t_STRA005R",
        "Status": 1,
        "ChannelName": "News Hindi",
        "Mode": false,
        "StartTime": "00:00:00:00",
        "Duration": "00:00:06:11",
        "idx": 0,
        "Thumbnail": "9e728a2800a28a2800a28a2800add3d6b0aa7fb6dc7fcf4ffc745006b8a5158ff6db145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145007fffd9",
        "SlugName": "EU 'growth boost from US trade deal'"
    },
    {
        "ClipName": "U.S. releases $250 mill_STRA005S",
        "Status": 2,
        "ChannelName": "News Hindi",
        "Mode": false,
        "StartTime": "00:00:00:00",
        "Duration": "00:00:32:16",
        "idx": 1,
               "Thumbnail": "9e728a2800a28a2800a28a2800add3d6b0aa7fb6dc7fcf4ffc745006b8a5158ff6db145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145007fffd9",
        "SlugName": "Liverpool FC continues to make losses"
    },
    {
        "ClipName": "SpaceX-2 Mission Launch_STRA005T",
        "Status": 3,
        "ChannelName": "News Hindi",
        "Mode": false,
        "StartTime": "00:00:00:00",
        "Duration": "00:04:20:04",
        "idx": 2,
        "Thumbnail": "9e728a2800a28a2800a28a2800add3d6b0aa7fb6dc7fcf4ffc745006b8a5158ff6db145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145001451450014514500145145007fffd9",
        "SlugName": "Latvia applies to enter eurozone"
    }
]
```

I want when comment. Status is 1 it displays a button in a webpage as a comment. Status is 2 also displays a button with name cue as goes on with comment. Status 3,4
how can I display the btn with comment status 1,2,3

Comment: can you give more info about what contains the array comments

Comment: you mean api data then i edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that uses a `switch` statement and return your output from that:

```
<div>
  {data.map(({ status }) => {
    const statusContent = () => {
      if (status === 1) {
        return <button>Option 1</button>;
      } else if (status === 2) {
        return <button>Option 2</button>;
      } else if (status === 3) {
        return <button>Option 3</button>;
      } else {
        return <button>Option 4</button>;
      }
    };

    return <div>{statusContent()}</div>;
  })}
</div>
```

Ideally, within JSX it's "cleaner" to a ternary operator. But in situations like this where there are multiple conditions, this would work fine.

Comment: Awesome :) Can you mark this as the accepted answer?